# Sitemap / RSS / Atom, SEO

Tags: seo, rss, sitemap, feed, atom-feed

So, I was about to make a regular sitemap.xml for my site, then I saw that both Google and Bing accept Atom and RSS as sitemaps.

My site is a forum, so there will be new pages created very frequently.

Will using an RSS/Atom feed cause new pages to be indexed more quickly than if I use a regular sitemap.xml?
What are the SEO benefits of one method vs another?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitemaps are better because they tell search engines about *all* of your content, not just the X number of newer threads that RSS and Atom feeds are limited to. Plus they offer extra information such as importance and other items that RSS and Atom do not offer.

Comment: And do any of the 3 options (or something else that I didn't mention) affect the speed of being indexed?

Comment: I can't say for sure but a sitemap should be faster. [Here's what a Google employee had to say about sitemaps and how Google uses them](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/30279/1253).